# How to put all print output from cmd to a txt file?

Tags: python, cmd

Can you help me identify what's wrong in this code? I want to put all the print output on the cmd to a txt file. This code only puts the last line.

```
import urllib.request  

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')  
for line in fhand:  
    z = line.decode().strip()
    with open('romeo.txt', 'w') as f:
        print(z, file=f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating and writing 'romeo.txt' file for every line of the content. Swap the for loop and the opening file. Something like this:

```
import urllib.request  

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt')  
with open('romeo.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in fhand:  
    z = line.decode().strip()
        print(z, file=f)
```

Comment: thanks for catching this. (indented the last 2 lines)